# How to specify number of layers in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to define a fully connected neural network in keras using tensorflow backend, I have a sample code but I dont know what it means.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=x.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=x.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=x.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=x.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1],activation='softmax'))
```

From the above code I want to know what is the number of inputs to my network, number of outputs, number of hidden layers and number of neurons in each layer. And what is the number coming after model.add(Dense ? assuming x.shape[1]=60.
What is the name of this network exacly? Should I call it a fully connected network or convolutional network?

Answer (score 0):

That should be quite easy.

1. For knowing about the model's inputs and outputs use,

   ```
   input_tensor = model.input
   output_tensor = model.output
   ```

   You can print these `tf.Tensor` objects to get the `shape` and `dtype`.
2. For fetching the Layers of a model use,

   ```
   layers = model.layers
   print( layers[0].units )
   ```

With these tricks you can easily get the input and output tensors for a model or its layer.